# Pattern to Prefixes and Suffixes in English

Tags: english, grammar, latin, greek, prefixes

I've come across a [list of English prefixes](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Category:English_prefixes&from=B) and remember learning in school about Latin and Greek being helpful for learning words in English based on prefixes/suffixes. I'm wondering though if there is a way to learn *all* of the English prefixes and suffixes by learning a set of languages or just a part of them or whatnot. If not all, then most of them. Basically I'm wondering if there is a system for learning the patterns of the prefixes / suffixes so that you could understand novel words without previously knowing their definition.

Comment: This answer, related to prefixes/suffixes might be of your interest: https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/a/3889/5471